# Can I install Oracle XE or any free version on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, failed-installation, oracle-xe, database-installation

I just wanna know if Oracle XE or any free available version of Oracle is compatible with any of the Ubuntu versions.

Comment: If you are not a very advanced Linux user, don't even think about it. It doesn't matter how much you know about Oracle - "not much" is not a problem; but not knowing much about Linux would be a huge problem. If you do want to learn Oracle on top of Linux, use Oracle Linux - it's free, and it works perfectly with Oracle database. Oracle Linux is essentially Red Hat Linux - you will learn a major dialect of Linux at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know:

- Ubuntu isn't certified with Oracle database
- 11gXE is an old version; it comes without support anyway
- so, if you hit any problems, don't expect "official" support from Oracle
- there are walkthrougs available on the Internet which show *how* to install 11gXE on Ubuntu, so it is *possible* (I never did it; never had to)

  - people who did it usually spent days if not weeks to make it work

Basically, YMMV.

Comment: is right, if you must have it on Ubuntu, then best to get a docker/vbox oracle linux environment for the DB to run inside of

Comment: Just to expand a bit .. There are several 'branches' to the Linux family tree and Ubuntu is an entirely different branch than the one that oracle was written for. On the web you will find some hacks to get oracle to install on Ubuntu but that's exactly what they are -- hacks.  Even if you get it installed, any future problems will be highly suspect.  If all you have is ubuntu, then best to use Docker or Virtual Box to create a VM running oracle linux - which is derived from Red Hat.

Comment: @EdStevens - "all you have is ubuntu" shouldn't be limiting. If one is able to install ubuntu, they can also install Oracle Linux, it's just as easy (or as difficult). I know, I did both - and exactly for the same reason this poster will do it too.

Comment: to support the point, I had experience with deploying 11g XE on Debian, that was not way too complicated, and that was somewhat stable in the end, however this was just an experiment and only for testing activities. Under no circumstances that should be considered for production database, it's way too risky

Comment: @mathguy - by "all you have is ubuntu" i mean that he has only one machine, and it is and must remain Ubuntu.  Like my personal laptop.  It is running ubuntu and it really makes not sense to wipe it and install oracle linux.  Everything must be done within the overall framework of ubuntu.  So I installed VBox and created several VM's, each running oracle linux.  I assume (possibly incorrectly) from the fact that the OP wants oracle XE and he has ubuntu, that this is really just a personal system.  I certainly wouldn't want to run anything 'real' on that setup.

Comment: @EdStevens - Right, I am blinded by personal experience. I installed Ubuntu just to learn how to use Oracle on Linux (I had been using it on Windows first), so it wasn't a big deal to uninstall and do a clean Oracle Linux installation. With that said, it is generally possible to free up some space and install Oracle Linux alongside Ubuntu on the same machine (without damaging the existing Ubuntu installation).

Comment: @mathguy - Ah, I forgot about the dual-boot option, having never used it myself.  :-)